# Merging multiple lists to one list of Objects in stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have code like this. It uses JSoap library. I am getting titles, magnets, seeds, leechers (these two together as TorrentStats) from torrent site. Now I want to merge them inside one List, of course it's pretty easy to do it in standard for loop but is there any way to map or flatmap them in stream?

```
Document html = Jsoup.connect(SEARCH_URL + phrase.replaceAll("\\s+", "%20")).get();

Elements elements1 = html.select(".detLink");
Elements elements2 = html.select("td > a[href~=magnet:]");
Elements elements3 = html.select("table[id~=searchResult] tr td[align~=right]");

List < String > titles = elements1.stream()
    .map(Element::text)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

List < String > magnets = elements2.stream()
    .map(e - > e.attr("href"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

List < TorrentStats > torrentStats = IntStream.iterate(0, i - > i + 2)
    .limit(elements3.size() / 2)
    .mapToObj(i - > new TorrentStats(Integer.parseInt(elements3.get(i).text()),
        Integer.parseInt(elements3.get(i + 1).text())))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

//is there any way to use map or flatmap to connect these 3 list into this one?
List < Torrent > torrents = new ArrayList < > ();
for (int i = 0; i < titles.size(); i++) {
    torrents.add(new Torrent(titles.get(i), magnets.get(i), torrentStats.get(i)));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `IntStream.range` to iterate over the indexes.

```
List<Torrent> torrents = IntStream.range(0, titles.size())
      .mapToObj(i -> new Torrent(titles.get(i), magnets.get(i), torrentStats.get(i)))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Oh, I did the same above when merging to TorrentStats <facepalm>, thank you

Comment: Ye, I was waiting maybe for another solutions but I think there will not be better or cleaner solution for this :)